# How can I block an Image using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML Website. I want to display it in an mobile app using HTML code. But I wan't to block / not load the original website background because it's very large and you can't see it mobile.
Is there a way to do it with HTML / CSS / JavaScript?

Comment: Question edited: [tag:java] removed, [tag:javascript] added as it does not look like your question has much to do with Java programming and you will want to attract the right experts to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use media queries to load the background image if the screen is larger than XX.
Add the media query to your CSS.

Change `div` to the element you're loading the background image on.

```
<style>
    @media (max-width:500px) {
      div {
        background-image: none;
      }
    }
</style>
```

** EDIT **

With mobile-first being the correct approach, it would be preferred only to add the background image when the viewport reaches the required size.

```
<style>
    @media (min-width: 644px) {
      div {
        background-image: url(/image/here.jpg);
      }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I can't change the code of the original site. Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't understand... If you can't change or add code how are you expecting to hide the background image on the site?

Comment: My website loads the stylesheet from another website which code I can't change.

Comment: I've updated my code... you'll need to add this to the head of your site below the current stylesheet link. Change the `div` to the selector that is used for the background image.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Media Queries** is the best way to apply different styles for an HTML document in different resolutions.

so, if you want to apply a different style (here *remove background image* in mobile resolutions) you may use Media queries

Eg.

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
   element{
      background:none;
   }
}
</style>
```